# Choose other user than current user in windows authentication Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

When I'm trying to create the entity model in Visual Studio 2010, I want to connect to a database that my current windows user can't access, how can I specify different login/password to access the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways that I can think of off the top of my head.

1. Use SQL Server Mixed Mode Authentication and have the application use a username and password controlled by SQL Server. That way you can create accounts on the SQL Server and connect as who ever you like when needed.
2. Have your application run under a different user account (Run As...). That way you can continue to use Windows Authentication on SQL Server and not have to open it up to additional ways of authenticating to it (i.e. mixed mode authentication)

There are pros and cons to each, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.